# Using jQuery script variable with a Bootstrap progress bar

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap progress bar to display a score calculated in a jQuery script (written for me by a developer).  It's part of a WordPress plugin, so a php file displays the page.  I have a variable (score) calculated in a js file and I need to insert it in the width value of the progress bar:

```
<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: <score>%"></div>
```

I'm not sure how to go about it, but I'd be very grateful for any assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, because you cant insert it with HTML. And if you have more progress-bars you can add an id.

```
var score = "Place here your score"
    $(".progress-bar").css({
       "width": score
    })
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was struggling for hours and hours with this, and your answer was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this in the JS file - find a way to reference the particular progress bar (can't say how without seeing more of your HTML, although if it had an id that would be easiest), and then set the width using, for example, jQuery's `.width`.

Although, if the value of `score` will not change between page loads, you may be better off inserting this using PHP. (something like `...style="width: <?php echo $score ?>%"...`)

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated.